# OR operator in NOTORM PHP

Tags: php, mysql, notorm

Two Tables defined as below:

```
----------   types -----------
 id      type    
  1        A
  2        B
  3        C

----------  subtypes ----------
 id   type_id    sub_type
  1     1      sub_type1
  2     2      sub_type1
  3     3      sub_type2
  4     1      sub_type3  
  5     2      sub_type2
```

My PHP NOTORM code is as below:

```
 $query = $db->types();
 $subTypeFilters = ['sub_type1','sub_type3'];

 function filteredQuery($subTypeFilters , $query){
    global $db; 
    $subTypeQuery ;
    for($i = 0 ; $i < count($subTypeFilters); $i++){

     // if($i>0)
     //    $subTypeQuery .= ' OR ' ;
      $subTypeQuery = $query('id' , $db->sub_type()->where('sub_type', $subTypeFilters[$i])->select('type_id'));
    }

echo   ($subTypeQuery);
return $subTypeQuery;
}

$query = filteredQuery($subTypeFilters , $query);
```

I am getting $subTypeQuery as `select * from types where (id in (1,2)) AND (id in (1))` so  finally I end up with only one type with id = 1,  how can I put OR operator in between to get all types which have subtypes given in array.

Comment: with AND you will only get 1. With OR you will get 1,2. Am I missing something ? The example is not a stellar one.

Comment: yes I want 1,2 both as final result.. I am beginner to notorm so what point am I missing?

Comment: then shoot for the first IN only as I see it :>

Comment: but there can be more elements in SubfilterArray i.e query can be like this.. (id in (1,,3,5,6) ) AND (id in (2,5,7)) AND (id in 2,5,6,8) in this case my desire answer should be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 when there is OR operator.

Comment: AND just limits, looks for what is in common. I know nothing about NOTORM, (just talking pure mysql or boolean logic), so keep that in mind

Comment: yeah.. in simple mysql query it is very easy to do this thing.

Comment: check this out: http://www.sitepoint.com/database-interaction-made-easy-with-notorm/#comment-1146851657